# Are there ways to perform postCSS processing withouth gulp or grunt. Only with help of maven?

Tags: maven, gruntjs, gulp, post-processing, post-processor

I want to perform postprocessing in my project with help of postCSS.
As I'm new in frontend I read only ways to perform it by frontend build system (grunt or gulp).
But maybe the ways to postpocess only with maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [postcss-cli](https://github.com/code42day/postcss-cli) to run it through the command line.

The command usage is pretty straight-forward.

```
 postcss [options] [-o output-file|-d output-directory] [input-file]
```

Also, if you are using `npm` along with a `package.json` file, I would advise you to add a [`run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "script": {
     "css": "postcss your options -go here"
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "postcss":"^4.1.13"
  }
}
```

So you can simply run `npm run css` from maven / CLI without having to worry about prefixing your command `node_modules/bin` and having your options in maven.